# Reading Local Security Policy From Service

Tags: c#, local-security-policy

I'm attempting to write an engine for basically scoring machines based on vulnerabilities fixed. I want to read the Local Security Policy and basically give points for more secure settings.

Not sure if this is important but I'm currently using a service to run the engine so far.

Sum up: **How can I read Window's Local Security Policy?**